# To use full calendar jquery plugin as google calendar

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

I am using jQuery fullcalendar plugin. Drag and resize options are given for events.

I like to add events and edit event as same as google calendar.

**Any other plugin is there to bring out google calendar functionality in jquery**

How to do this?

**Updated**

```
....

eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    alert('Event: ' + calEvent.id);
    // alert('Coordinates: ' + jsEvent.pageX + ',' + jsEvent.pageY);
    // alert('View: ' + view.name);

    // change the border color just for fun
    // $(this).css('border-color', 'red');

    tb_show("Edit Event","event_edit.php?event_obj="+calEvent+"&event_title="+calEvent.title+"&keepThis=true&TB_iframe=true&height=250&width=400");
},

.....
```

`calEvent` is an object and I am calling an iframe thickbox popup so I cant maintain object.

`calEvent` in another page.

Comment: I am not sure what is your problem here. I just recently completed quite big calendaring project. I used jquery fullcalendar plugin. I think it is a good base to build somethink almost the same as google calendar. My advice is stick to this great plugin.

Comment: How to make add, edit events using popup same as google calender. i cant fetch the values

Comment: I am using jquery to display a "popup" - hide show div with a form to submit new data to the database. Then I add the data using ajax with JSON. The events of the jquery fullcalendar are fetched using php - see this example: http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.1/demos/json.html

If you have any specific questions please do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: i am using thick box for editing events. i cant retain object. i try to follow your way of ajax updation of values. without using thickbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is my "add event" part inside of the fullcalendar init:

```
select: function(start, end, allDay) {
                var calendars = getAjaxData('calendar/calendarsJson');


                var txt = '<h3>Add event:</h3>\n\
                           <div class="clear"></div>\n\
                           <p><label>'+CI.lang.language.what+':</label><input type="text"  name="title" value="" /></p>\n\
                           <p><label>'+CI.lang.language.where+':</label><input type="text"  name="location" value="" /></p>\n\
                           <p><label>'+CI.lang.language.description+':</label></p>\n\
                           <p><textarea  name="description"></textarea></p>';
                txt += '<p><label>'+CI.lang.language.calendar+':</label>\n\
                            <select name="id_calendar">';
                for(i=0;i<calendars.length;i++) {
                    txt += '<option value="'+calendars[i].id_calendar+'">'+calendars[i].title+'</option>';
                }
                txt += '</select></p>';
                txt += '<br />';                    

                var btns = {};
                btns[CI.lang.language.create_event] = true
                btns[CI.lang.language.cancel] = false;

                $.prompt(txt,{
                    prefix:'event_box',
                    callback: addeventnow,
                    buttons: btns
                });                

                function addeventnow(v,m,f){

                    if(f && v){
                        var classN = getAjaxData('calendar/getClassJson/'+f.id_calendar);
                        var nEvent = {
                            title: f.title,
                            description: f.description,
                            location: f.location,
                            start: start,
                            end: end,
                            allDay: allDay,
                            className: classN,
                            id_calendar: f.id_calendar

                        };
                        if (f.title) {
                            calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                                nEvent,
                                false // make the event "stick"
                            );
                        }
                        addEvent(nEvent);
                        calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                    }

                     calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');

                }

            },
```

Dont' bother the "language" and "CI" stuff..this is just the was to localize strings with codeigniter which was my framework of choice.